# Proxy Error in RoR web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I have an RoR app and while deleting content from this app, I am encountering the following error. Although when I refresh the webpage after this error, the content is deleted in the request.

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /abc/xyz/source/23.

Reason: Error reading from remote server.
```

This is an Apache Web server.

Can you please help me find what could be the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 1):

The  invalid response from an upstream server is generated when Apache web server does not receive a valid HTTP response from the upstream server.

The reason may be because of the following things;

1. The application did not respond in time and the request from Apache timed out.
2. May be network device blocking the request.

You need to add/increase the timeout limit in httpd.conf  file of your application.